# Cannot install Ubuntu

Tags: installation, 12.10, windows-7, wubi

I'm using Windows 7 and when I try to install and this message appears:

```
"An error ocurred: Could not retrieve the required installation files
For more information, please see the log file:
c:\users\.............\wubi-12.10-rev273.log"
```

The final part of the log ->

```
12-17 13:43 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-17 13:43 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Ubuntu 12.10 "Quantal Quetzal" - Release i386 (20121017.2)
12-17 13:43 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Ubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '12.10', 'build': '20121017.2', 'codename': 'Quantal Quetzal', 'arch': 'i386'}
12-17 13:43 INFO   Distro: Found a valid CD for Ubuntu: F:\
12-17 13:43 INFO   root: Running the uninstaller...
12-17 13:43 INFO   CommonBackend: This is the uninstaller running
12-17 13:43 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: __init__...
12-17 13:43 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: on_init...
12-17 13:43 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\TASSO'~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylED6A.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-17 13:43 INFO   WindowsFrontend: Operation cancelled
12-17 13:43 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: frontend.quit
12-17 13:43 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: frontend.on_quit
12-17 13:43 DEBUG  root: application.on_quit
12-17 13:43 INFO   root: sys.exit
```

Comment: Could you upload the complete log to some pastebin service like http://pastebin.com/?

Comment: Now is giving another error in the log...
http://pastebin.com/C1pvPQzn

Comment: You can try the option `--skipmd5check`. Maybe this helps. See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Can_I_force_Wubi_to_skip_the_md5_checks.3F

Comment: That's not a good idea unless you know the ISO is good (i.e. with a development release). Remove the CD from `F:` and let it download a new ISO or the diskimage. Do you have an apostrophe in your user name? That's might be causing some issues: `command=C:\Users\TASSO'~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBC2.tmp\bin\resize2fs.exe -f C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk 17744M`

Comment: It worked! I skiped the md5 check and it worked. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 2):

*This was answered in comments.*

> You can try the option `--skipmd5check`. Maybe this helps. See also
>   [wiki.ubuntu.com/…](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Can_I_force_Wubi_to_skip_the_md5_checks.3F).

– [qbi](https://askubuntu.com/users/236/qbi) [Dec 17 '12 at 22:28](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229956/cannot-install-ubuntu#comment284089_229956)

The OP [reported this worked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229956/cannot-install-ubuntu#comment284366_229956). But there are other alternatives:

> *[Skipping the integrity check is]* not a good idea unless you know the ISO is good (i.e. with a development release).
>
> Remove the CD from F: and let it download a new ISO or the diskimage.
>
> Do you have an apostrophe in your user name? *[That]* might be causing
>   some issues:
>
> ```
> command=C:\Users\TASSO'~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBC2.tmp\bin\resize2fs.exe -f C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk 17744M
> ```

– [bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc) [Dec 18 '12 at 1:12](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229956/cannot-install-ubuntu#comment284115_229956)